# When will retrofit add call adapter factory support for coroutine just like Rx officially?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I have been working with Retrofit for around 3 years and since the introduction of RxAndroid square up added a converter factory to streamline response to RxStream. Now i dont see any official addition for Coroutines. Though i found an experimental suite developed by Jake Wharton which has the convertor but i really doubt the reliability of it in the live projects.

Any ideas ?

**implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-experimental-adapter:1.0.0'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently Retrofit is built in suspending function, so you no longer need to return it as Deffered. just return real metadata. like this

```
@GET("/users")
suspend fun getUsers(): List<Users>
```

or, you want to read my presentation about this at https://s.id/kotlin-add

Answer (score 1):

**Coroutines support was added in Retrofit 2.6.0**

In app.gradle

```
def retrofitVersion = '2.6.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
```

API Service Interface

```
 @GET("api/?")
suspend fun getImages(
    @Query("key") apiKey: String,
    @Query("q") query: String,
    @Query("image_type") imageType: String,
    @Query("pretty") yesOrNo: Boolean
    ):ApiResponse
```

This is not the correct appraoch but just an example

```
fun getImagesForPicassoView() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            apiResponse.postValue(apiService.getImages(Constants.API_KEY,"food","photo",true))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067) article Retrofit already has support for coroutines. Hasn't? In order to find it you couldn't spend 5 seconds instead of writing a question here?!

Just create suspend methods in your Retrofit interface and directly return your data object.

```
@GET("api/todo")
suspend fun getTodo(@Path(value = "id") todoId: Int): Todo
```

Read more in the link.

Comment: I am asking about the callAdapterFactory.Your answer is not relevant to my question

Comment: Yeah, that is why you've accepted the same answer.